# Use external Font Swf to change font of a dynamic text Field in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a as3 project in which the user select a font from Combo Box and that font SWF should be loaded Dynamically and then i need to change the font of the Dynamic text field.

I have  swf font files downloaded from www.isarie.com

My question is that how can i load the font swf dynamically from server and add them to the library and how can i use that swf to change the font of dynamic text field.

if there are embedded fonts in library then i can access them using this-

```
var fontList:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
for( var i:int=0; i<fontList.length; i++ ){
    trace( "font: " + fontList[ i ].fontName );
}
```

But How to use dynamically loaded Font swf as a font type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know font class name, so:

```
 var fontClass:Class = swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("FontClassName") as Class;
    Font.registerFont(fontClass);
```

otherwise you can use FontLoader class by Denis Kolyako, you can get it here: http://etcs.ru/pre/FontLoaderDemo/